# Ajuda com código(parece ser hexadecimal)

Tags: criptografia, hexadecimal

Olá, no meu curso teve uma brincadeira, quem conseguisse decifrar o código ganharia um premio, eu tentei em hexadecimal, porem não consegui nada.

```
51 44 52 20 59 44 20 57 44 52 20 4a 48
51 57 4c 4f 50 48 51 57 48 20 51 48 56
56 44 20 45 52 44 20 51 52 4c 57 58 20
48 56 46 58 55 44 55 44 4c 59 44 20 46
52 51 57 55 44 20 44 20 50 52 55 57 48
20 47 44 20 4f 58 43 20 54 58 20 49 58
4f 4a 58 55 44
```

Obs: Sei que isso não tem muito a ver com programação, porem apreciaria muito a ajuda de vocês nisso.

Obs²: Eu nem vou participar da brincadeira, só estou realmente curioso.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assim como você, vi que era um código hexadecimal. Então converti os dados para valores da tabela ASCII [aqui](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm). Me dando esse resultado:

```
"QDR YD WDR JHQWLOPHQWH QHVVD ERD QRLWX HVFXUDUDLYD FRQWUD D PRUWH GD OXC TX IXOJXUD"
```

Depois de receber esse resultado, achei parecido com um código gerado pela [cifra de César](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifra_de_C%C3%A9sar). Então fui em uma [ferramenta online](http://www.dcode.fr/caesar-cipher) de *brute force* e coloquei o resultado do passo anterior, que trouxe um resultado satisfatório (com o shift de +3 na mensagem original):

```
"NAO VA TAO GENTILMENTE NESSA BOA NOITU ESCURARAIVA CONTRA A MORTE DA LUZ QU FULGURA"
```

OBS: É possível que tenha ocorrido algum erro durante alguma das conversões, pois foi feito em ferramentas que não testei antes. Porém a essência da mensagem é essa e o processo a ser feito é esse.

Comment: Eu cheguei a pensar na cifra de César, porem não achei nenhuma ferramenta que fizesse a cifra de César.

Answer (score 2):

Isso é hexadicimal sim

Tradução é essa

```
QDR YD WDR JH
QWLOPHQWH QHV
VD ERD QRLWX
HVFXUDUDLYD F
RQWUD D PRUWH
 GD OXC TX IX
OJXUD
```

Agora só falta o função matematica que desembaralha isso

O nosso amigo achou até uma tradução, mas deve ser algum codigo de comando cifrado.